# Exporting eye tracking data on hololens 2

Tags: hololens, eye-tracking

I'm trying to do a study seeing where surgeons are looking in the operating room. I want to record them doing a surgery with the hololens 2. Is this possible? I do not need any AR features. Just a videorecording of the operating with eye-tracking coordinates with time stamps.

I looked around and can only seem to find eye tracking with AR interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the video, you can try MRC, please refer to [Mixed reality capture overview - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/mixed-reality-capture-overview). Regarding the coordinates of eye gaze, you can get it via **[CoreServices.InputSystem.EyeGazeProvider.GazeCursor.Position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.imixedrealitygazeprovider.gazecursor?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.8.0#microsoft-mixedreality-toolkit-input-imixedrealitygazeprovider-gazecursor)**. For the camera can capture it, you can modify the **[CoreServices.InputSystem.EyeGazeProvider.GazeCursorPrefab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.imixedrealitygazeprovider.gazecursorprefab?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.8.0#microsoft-mixedreality-toolkit-input-imixedrealitygazeprovider-gazecursorprefab)** to make it visible by default, you can also modify it in the profile. And you can get the timestamp via **[CoreServices.InputSystem.EyeGazeProvider.Timestamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.imixedrealityeyegazeprovider.timestamp?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.8.0#microsoft-mixedreality-toolkit-input-imixedrealityeyegazeprovider-timestamp)**. Also, please refer to [Eye Tracking - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/eye-tracking/eye-tracking-main?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) for more information.